# JAWS not reading a dynamic checkbox label

Tags: checkbox, dynamic, jaws-screen-reader

I have an Angular 4 app which should supports JAWS. I have a list of check boxes that is displayed dynamically. JAWS is not able to read the label that is set to the check box. How do I set the label/aria-label in the below code:

```
<input [tabindex]="x.tabIndex" aria-label="e.name" [id]="e.name" type="checkbox"  [checked]="e.selected" [value]="e.name"/>
```

Comment: Just add a label below like this,                                                                                                
                <label  hidden label for="{{e.name}}">{{e.name}}</label>

Answer (score 0):

Please specify role to element - role="checkbox"